# How to hide option in dropdown in select2 after selecting the option

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core, jquery-select2, razor-pages

I have a multiselect select2 dropdown as shown below
[Original Dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aN9tD.png)
after selecting 2 options(A and B),
[Options Selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhD18.png)
I want only **C** to be appeared in the option
desired output is
[Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZ8MW.png)
I am using razor pages in c# with jquery as shown below
**cshtml:**

```
<select id="selector"
        class="col-md-24"
        multiple="multiple"
        asp-for="Payload.List"
        asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.DropDown, "Id", "Name"))">
</select>
```

**JQuery**

```js
$('#selector').on("select2:selecting", function (e) {

    $('#' + e.params.args.data._resultId).css("display", "none");
});
```

here _resultId has the id of generated options, I wanted to hide the option with that Id. But It is not working
can anyone please help

Comment: `<option>` elements can't be hidden, but you can re-build the `innerHTML` of the `select`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what is the version of select2 you use. For my project I use select2 latest version `4.1.0-rc.0`, just apply the css like below:

```
@section Scripts
{
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.1.0-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" integrity="sha512-aD9ophpFQ61nFZP6hXYu4Q/b/USW7rpLCQLX6Bi0WJHXNO7Js/fUENpBQf/+P4NtpzNX0jSgR5zVvPOJp+W2Kg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.1.0-rc.0/js/select2.min.js" integrity="sha512-4MvcHwcbqXKUHB6Lx3Zb5CEAVoE9u84qN+ZSMM6s7z8IeJriExrV3ND5zRze9mxNlABJ6k864P/Vl8m0Sd3DtQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>    
    <script>
        $("#selector").select2();
    </script>
    <style>
        .select2-results__option--selected {
            display: none;
        }        
    </style>
}
```

If above css does not work for your project and you use other older version, try to apply the css below:

```
.select2-results__option[aria-selected=true] { display: none;}
```